# Apple reject app "We found that your app crashed on iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1.2 "

Tags: ios, crash, app-store-connect, itunes, crash-reports

Once again apple has rejected my app,their say that there is a crash testing on iOS 7.1.2 with iPhone 5s device, below you will find the crash log, can anyone give me help? I do not understand where the problem is ... Help me.

Thanks for your time and your cooperation.

Regards

Francesco M.

Crash log report and message from Apple

We found that your app crashed on iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1.2, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, tapping any button leads the app to crash.

This occurred when your app was used:

- Offline
- On Wi-Fi
- On cellular networkWe

This is the crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 3C215575-D43B-4B9F-8162-321AD61A5D21
CrashReporter Key:   c746f175d2b7240a57e3e86ae8589dfcb0d7270f
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             BlogNews [18200]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/B397886B-5C8A-4043-8EE3-C01B4A179681/BlogNews.app/BlogNews
Identifier:          com.FrancescoMaino.BlogNews
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-09-09 16:25:08.478 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x2df48ecb 0x38b22ce7 0x2df4c7f7 0x2df4b0f7 0x2de9a058 0x2e929117 0x2df13f0f 0x2df13b2b 0x2df11eb3 0x2de7c729 0x2de7c50b 0x32db56d3 0x307dd871 0x65ce7 0x65ca0)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390d71f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913f7b3 pthread_kill + 55
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39087ff5 abort + 73
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x384d698b abort_message + 71
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x384ef6e3 default_terminate_handler() + 251
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38b22f7b _objc_terminate() + 191
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x384ed1b1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x384ecd13 __cxa_rethrow + 99
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38b22e2b objc_exception_rethrow + 39
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2de7c79b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 639
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2de7c507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
11  GraphicsServices                0x32db56cf GSEventRunModal + 135
12  UIKit                           0x307dd86d UIApplicationMain + 1133
13  BlogNews                        0x00065ce3 0x61000 + 19683
14  BlogNews                        0x00065c9c 0x61000 + 19612

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390c4804 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x39013051 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 229
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3900d2df _dispatch_mgr_thread + 35

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390d7c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cc1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390d7c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cc1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eec3b59 JSC::Lexer<unsigned char>::lex(JSC::JSTokenData*, JSC::JSTokenLocation*, unsigned int, bool) + 893
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eeda31f JSC::ASTBuilder::Statement JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseVarDeclaration<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&) + 159
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eec74d5 JSC::ASTBuilder::Statement JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseStatement<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&, JSC::Identifier const*&, unsigned int*) + 845
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eec7481 JSC::ASTBuilder::Statement JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseStatement<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&, JSC::Identifier const*&, unsigned int*) + 761
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eec7023 JSC::ASTBuilder::SourceElements JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseSourceElements<(JSC::SourceElementsMode)0, JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&) + 131
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eec6c8d JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseInner() + 201
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eefbe7d WTF::PassRefPtr<JSC::FunctionBodyNode> JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parse<JSC::FunctionBodyNode>(JSC::ParserError&) + 73
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eefbde7 WTF::PassRefPtr<JSC::FunctionBodyNode> JSC::parse<JSC::FunctionBodyNode>(JSC::VM*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::FunctionParameters*, JSC::Identifier const&, JSC::JSParserStrictness, JSC::JSParserMode, JSC::ParserError&) + 95
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eefbbc7 JSC::UnlinkedFunctionExecutable::codeBlockFor(JSC::VM&, JSC::JSScope*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::DebuggerMode, JSC::ProfilerMode, JSC::ParserError&) + 79
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eefba93 JSC::FunctionExecutable::produceCodeBlockFor(JSC::JSScope*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSObject*&) + 195
10  JavaScriptCore                  0x2ef007ff JSC::FunctionExecutable::compileForCallInternal(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSScope*, JSC::JITCode::JITType, unsigned int) + 43
11  JavaScriptCore                  0x2eefb7eb JSC::LLInt::setUpCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Instruction*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSValue, JSC::LLIntCallLinkInfo*) + 623
12  JavaScriptCore                  0x2eef25cb llint_slow_path_call + 119
13  JavaScriptCore                  0x2eef6f11 llint_op_call + 197
14  JavaScriptCore                  0x2ef0054b JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 67
15  JavaScriptCore                  0x2efd23cf JSC::functionProtoFuncApply(JSC::ExecState*) + 703
16  JavaScriptCore                  0x2eef7131 llint_native_call_trampoline + 63
17  JavaScriptCore                  0x2ef0054b JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 67
18  JavaScriptCore                  0x2efd23cf JSC::functionProtoFuncApply(JSC::ExecState*) + 703
19  JavaScriptCore                  0x2eef7131 llint_native_call_trampoline + 63
20  JavaScriptCore                  0x2ef0054b JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 67
21  JavaScriptCore                  0x2efd23cf JSC::functionProtoFuncApply(JSC::ExecState*) + 703
22  JavaScriptCore                  0x2eef7131 llint_native_call_trampoline + 63
23  JavaScriptCore                  0x2ef0054b JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 67
24  JavaScriptCore                  0x2efdd1ed JSC::boundFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 349
25  JavaScriptCore                  0x2eef7131 llint_native_call_trampoline + 63
26  JavaScriptCore                  0x2ef0054b JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 67
27  WebCore                         0x3638efa3 WebCore::JSMainThreadExecState::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 143
28  WebCore                         0x365785db WebCore::JSEventListener::handleEvent(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*, WebCore::Event*) + 515
29  WebCore                         0x36536797 WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*, WebCore::EventTargetData*, WTF::Vector<WebCore::RegisteredEventListener, 1ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>&) + 483
30  WebCore                         0x364356d1 WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*) + 181
31  WebCore                         0x3643584f WebCore::EventContext::handleLocalEvents(WebCore::Event*) const + 59
32  WebCore                         0x364353d3 WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatch() + 563
33  WebCore                         0x3643519b WebCore::EventDispatchMediator::dispatchEvent(WebCore::EventDispatcher*) const + 7
34  WebCore                         0x36434a61 WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WebCore::Node*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::EventDispatchMediator>) + 153
35  WebCore                         0x36434921 WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 97
36  WebCore                         0x36586237 non-virtual thunk to WebCore::HTMLScriptElement::dispatchLoadEvent() + 51
37  WebCore                         0x3657f609 WebCore::ScriptElement::execute(WebCore::CachedScript*) + 217
38  WebCore                         0x3657f49d WebCore::ScriptRunner::timerFired(WebCore::Timer<WebCore::ScriptRunner>*) + 309
39  WebCore                         0x3638d8bd WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 133
40  WebCore                         0x3638d80f WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 23
41  CoreFoundation                  0x2df13f0d __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 13
42  CoreFoundation                  0x2df13b27 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 791
43  CoreFoundation                  0x2df11eaf __CFRunLoopRun + 1215
44  CoreFoundation                  0x2de7c725 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
45  CoreFoundation                  0x2de7c507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
46  WebCore                         0x3641ac71 RunWebThread(void*) + 417
47  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e957 _pthread_body + 139
48  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e8c7 _pthread_start + 99
49  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390c4a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390c4849 mach_msg + 37
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2df135e5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 153
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2df11d05 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2de7c725 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2de7c507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
6   Foundation                      0x2e8bd23d +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 317
7   Foundation                      0x2e932a0b __NSThread__main__ + 1059
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e957 _pthread_body + 139
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e8c7 _pthread_start + 99
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390d7c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cc1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390d7c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cc1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390d7c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cc1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390d6f2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913df63 _pthread_cond_wait + 519
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913eddd pthread_cond_timedwait + 41
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eeab467 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 103
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eeab295 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 89
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eea8971 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 13
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e957 _pthread_body + 139
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e8c7 _pthread_start + 99
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390d6f2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913df63 _pthread_cond_wait + 519
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913ed9d pthread_cond_wait + 37
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2f049cb3 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 75
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2f049d0d JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 49
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eea8971 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 13
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e957 _pthread_body + 139
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e8c7 _pthread_start + 99
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390d7434 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2df174df __CFSocketManager + 483
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e957 _pthread_body + 139
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e8c7 _pthread_start + 99
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390c4a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390c4849 mach_msg + 37
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x390132a1 _dispatch_mach_msg_send + 285
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x3900de11 dispatch_mach_send + 169
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x3914d1a3 _xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_f + 95
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x3914d0b1 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 137
6   SystemConfiguration             0x3075482d __SCNetworkReachabilityServer_targetStatus + 173
7   SystemConfiguration             0x30734493 __SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags + 307
8   SystemConfiguration             0x30734d07 SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags + 187
9   CFNetwork                       0x2db360c9 SocketStream::Reachability::schedule(dispatch_queue_s*) + 25
10  CFNetwork                       0x2db35f51 SocketStream::addNetworkReachability_NoLock() + 109
11  CFNetwork                       0x2db35e3f SocketStream::socketCallbackConnectLocked(SocketStreamSignalHolder*, void const*) + 263
12  CFNetwork                       0x2db35cf7 SocketStream::socketCallback(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*) + 87
13  CFNetwork                       0x2db35c67 SocketStream::_SocketCallBack_stream(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*, void*) + 55
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2df160b7 __CFSocketPerformV0 + 371
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2df13fad __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 13
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2df134f9 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 337
17  CoreFoundation                  0x2df11c63 __CFRunLoopRun + 627
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2de7c725 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2de7c507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
20  WebCore                         0x36463c5b WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 251
21  JavaScriptCore                  0x2eea8971 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 13
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e957 _pthread_body + 139
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e8c7 _pthread_start + 99
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 13 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390d6f2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913df63 _pthread_cond_wait + 519
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913ed9d pthread_cond_wait + 37
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eeab439 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 57
4   WebCore                         0x3654ef09 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WTF::Function<void ()> > WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool (WTF::Function<void ()>*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WTF::Function<void ()>*), double) + 105
5   WebCore                         0x3654ee8f WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 163
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x2eea8971 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 13
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e957 _pthread_body + 139
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913e8c7 _pthread_start + 99
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390d7c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cc1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3913cad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3907aa8d
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3adc418c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x001925a4
    r8: 0x175a6b50    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x000770af     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x00192598      lr: 0x3913f7b7      pc: 0x390d71f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0x61000 - 0x80fff BlogNews armv7s  <3309d6ef509e34dba07b1ea314c62290> /var/mobile/Applications/B397886B-5C8A-4043-8EE3-C01B4A179681/BlogNews.app/BlogNews
0x2be1b000 - 0x2be3b6aa dyld armv7s  <4d05d388718832c99cdd4e74aeb07d51> /usr/lib/dyld
0x2cc64000 - 0x2cd4dff5 RawCamera armv7s  <403adecbf3593e8a9e81beea174f8a01> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x2cd60000 - 0x2cda5ffa AGXGLDriver armv7s  <0869d4aa192634e4b4e41f78217dade2> /System/Library/Extensions/AGXGLDriver.bundle/AGXGLDriver
0x2cdb5000 - 0x2ceb7fff AVFoundation armv7s  <0d19d677cf523e18accb93523ee9b269> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x2ceb8000 - 0x2cee0ff4 libAVFAudio.dylib armv7s  <6c83d8e70b2e398f9a643de18a507401> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x2cee1000 - 0x2cee1fff Accelerate armv7s  <58ca068138d93e988a34a0c8c34b0b11> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x2ceeb000 - 0x2d0b8fda vImage armv7s  <9923548d8ed23bb1b1020130b5d38dab> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x2d0b9000 - 0x2d19bfff libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <48f7680a8fd83251ad8415bb090408c3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x2d19c000 - 0x2d454fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <2547383dc88d3329827b4d76768915ee> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x2d455000 - 0x2d4c3ff7 libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <83036da6f5d9308bb5fad06b2d29bac9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x2d4c4000 - 0x2d4d6ff3 libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <addc52a9647f3269965a750366ebed70> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x2d4d7000 - 0x2d4d7fff vecLib armv7s  <4a647b20c3f03490aae530226350a4cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x2d4d8000 - 0x2d4f8ffe Accounts armv7s  <7dbe9726167b36a38cf1a73eb313f9ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x2d4fa000 - 0x2d561ff3 AddressBook armv7s  <081495c24868358ea3f06e320fba44f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x2d7cf000 - 0x2daebff0 AudioToolbox armv7s  <056c504e1dd73ed4bbb54f57fa3dc873> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x2daec000 - 0x2dc0aff0 CFNetwork armv7s  <ed4b37345fca3e02bc3d2bbcac484b16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x2dc0b000 - 0x2dc66ff7 CoreAudio armv7s  <cf2658996f5c30d394af6ad906d8e0af> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x2dc67000 - 0x2dc7efff CoreBluetooth armv7s  <6fd36c8dc6be34ec88b5179e76ce246d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x2dc7f000 - 0x2de73067 CoreData armv7s  <a060f165568c31289760beb020e70f2e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x2de74000 - 0x2dfb7ff0 CoreFoundation armv7s  <83decfd26c653905912f5cdb8743f5d9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x2dfb8000 - 0x2e0dcffb CoreGraphics armv7s  <840c99b38b9f3ef497079f300ff15a1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x2e0de000 - 0x2e119ff0 libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7s  <f8e0113922b03325a82471e0ef77d7a1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x2e11b000 - 0x2e125ff8 libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib armv7s  <8a3e3045c8b732389f72dd226c1c1e54> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x2e30a000 - 0x2e324ff3 libRIP.A.dylib armv7s  <68accf992a733f58a04315603459e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x2e325000 - 0x2e3feffc CoreImage armv7s  <706f78907a5d3146b6d9c0382693a112> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x2e3ff000 - 0x2e44eff7 CoreLocation armv7s  <c20e4e3610743dc3affe4480639a16f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x2e486000 - 0x2e501ffb CoreMedia armv7s  <df4f98e752493f7daeb9166940a33dba> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x2e502000 - 0x2e5aaffb CoreMotion armv7s  <55bfab09e92b30d782ec33decd5f8d15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x2e5ab000 - 0x2e603ff7 CoreTelephony armv7s  <ad42b931d27832fa83ed5019f37a6afa> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x2e604000 - 0x2e694ff3 CoreText armv7s  <1eb3fd81e1203680a1ad0eecd4273594> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x2e695000 - 0x2e6a4fff CoreVideo armv7s  <b1c668f2ae323039b02bb52c4a4172b8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x2e865000 - 0x2ea4fff3 Foundation armv7s  <52121842f9863ab49b775758dd05db0b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x2ec31000 - 0x2ec87ff3 IOKit armv7s  <827281a0bc2e3120bc40be79b7e3026b> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x2ec88000 - 0x2ee98ffd ImageIO armv7s  <ec4acdf658dd3dec9d2c325db835d987> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x2ee99000 - 0x2f0e5ff7 JavaScriptCore armv7s  <12b8c035858737c792488a582909734f> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x2f196000 - 0x2f19aff3 MediaAccessibility armv7s  <a44ef28b46f236d5a76b63a08976e1dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x2f19b000 - 0x2f398fff MediaPlayer armv7s  <3016d0095677399ea36a5339fe67c291> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x2f399000 - 0x2f69fff3 MediaToolbox armv7s  <95a2680ee0ba372fa13fb8a683178e67> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x2f74c000 - 0x2f7afffe MobileCoreServices armv7s  <c3ab5b49a79334a0bcc84247b3132de6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x2f83f000 - 0x30125ff1 libLLVMContainer.dylib armv7s  <0d174adad6523ad1baed18f98a89d5e8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libLLVMContainer.dylib
0x30126000 - 0x301f6ffe GLEngine armv7s  <ee51dc607a0e39f8a3f0f5cc84363a9c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x301f7000 - 0x301fffff OpenGLES armv7s  <df9830a0248d36e5a9fabb2e633e9001> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x30201000 - 0x30201fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <6f98aa42a1593958a5455706156e9402> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x30202000 - 0x30205ffe libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7s  <d58db35c909f3a5394c40adf17cc1188> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x30206000 - 0x30209ffe libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <38ff1c7f12f83f8bac062e8daf9d4c10> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x3020a000 - 0x30211fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <a92cda33404b339da0e84a5fe133e06e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x30212000 - 0x30252ffc libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <7d912d8e3a453456a6e2d806b59aa448> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x30253000 - 0x30387ffe libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7s  <ccc9b565091c362d9db0a126df0a8950> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x303ea000 - 0x30531fff QuartzCore armv7s  <d5174e25cef83958adf812e37c93a41e> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30532000 - 0x30588ff1 QuickLook armv7s  <4ca86ffb65013bf881d7af2ff4b9790b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3058b000 - 0x305cdffb Security armv7s  <1e4881d7baad301d86c74515fea45c36> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3071d000 - 0x3076cfff SystemConfiguration armv7s  <3d6772f0ad5938558a4bc677965db338> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3076f000 - 0x30ee2ffd UIKit armv7s  <e6756dd481773242b35fa4db5378453b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x30ee3000 - 0x30f31ff3 VideoToolbox armv7s  <584a3e65bebe3025a2656cbf0c53a7a5> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x31138000 - 0x31139ff7 AGXCompilerConnection armv7s  <a976a477c2a834fb82c2c460e31c5f3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AGXCompilerConnection.framework/AGXCompilerConnection
0x3113a000 - 0x31169ffa AGXCompilerCore armv7s  <469a6c21e747397dadbfae7ee35ff416> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AGXCompilerCore.framework/AGXCompilerCore
0x312a3000 - 0x312a7fff AggregateDictionary armv7s  <b613b360be4f31948901570de6a079d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x31585000 - 0x31599ffb AirTraffic armv7s  <a51adbb21cff3333a112544baf944a11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x31903000 - 0x31941ff3 AppSupport armv7s  <4f0f918a35d733e9b6f49b785ffbf233> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31a27000 - 0x31a37ffc ApplePushService armv7s  <06d7dae5ed5b37f1b4eb56f2d12fac59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x31a38000 - 0x31a3efff AppleSRP armv7s  <e1db5ed3b8e034ce94f260077c96cea8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x31a6b000 - 0x31a77ffb AssetsLibraryServices armv7s  <19f6f222ffd83c34b022213e4e427815> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x31ac1000 - 0x31ac4ffd BTLEAudioController armv7s  <7ae2e740df58350e877d2573d4c0f766> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x31ac5000 - 0x31aeaffb BackBoardServices armv7s  <1ab89a11a7a834e4a36de79352bd9f6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x31aed000 - 0x31af2ffc BluetoothManager armv7s  <61ec3ec9b9073254bc8deccc40cc4b31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x31af3000 - 0x31b17ff7 Bom armv7s  <bf26b007d10337299e84e9c498b3378d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x31bb8000 - 0x31bc0fff CaptiveNetwork armv7s  <fb377104cf243743936d565eea038284> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31bc1000 - 0x31c9dff5 Celestial armv7s  <8c5698e317e6352eadea1e2bf93fd95c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x31caa000 - 0x31caffff CertUI armv7s  <78cc91d2d6b730ee86ea2a768d666d4a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x31d7b000 - 0x31d9bffd ChunkingLibrary armv7s  <9232ff4b2da43310a989090f5ae79547> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x31dec000 - 0x31df7fff CommonUtilities armv7s  <9317cb2858663a8b872b5bcb11453aeb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x31df8000 - 0x31dfcfff CommunicationsFilter armv7s  <53315d7fbfee3bf095fff818731fe781> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
0x31e8d000 - 0x31e8ffff ConstantClasses armv7s  <c910908091933017a5e778cb99a1b713> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x31ecf000 - 0x31ed1fff CoreAUC armv7s  <4296dced79b730fab4a92ee64a15ebae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x32166000 - 0x32184fff CoreServicesInternal armv7s  <6ccdd53c1e5a38f2b26689ef2c581e4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x32185000 - 0x32186ffd CoreSurface armv7s  <19b928f48fd33cbe9a84800e6fd4f6cd> /Syste
```

Comment: Hard to say. Did they provide any steps to reproduce? Have you tested your app on an iPhone 5s running 7.1.2 by yourself? Have you tried to turn of networking on the device and see how your app reacts?

Comment: Hello, i don't have an iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1.2... how can i test it ?

Comment: Set up a build on TestFlight or something and maybe we can help you.

Comment: I recently got rejected with the same reason "We found that your app crashed on iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1.2". I got crash logs, and you could actually tell that it wasn't a real device they were running it on.

The problem with my app was that they were, for some strange reason, running the iPhone app in an iPad simulator, which (for obvious reasons) doesn't have the iMessage facility up and running.

Comment: You have to symbolicate the crash report with Xcode. That will show you where in your code the app crashed. There are plenty of posts here on how to do that.

Comment: If i create a set up build on TestFlight someone can help me ?

Comment: i don't have crash on xcode, how can send an app to itunes if have error problem, the compiler apert you and u can't send the app to itunes

Comment: Read this - it cannot get anymore step by step than this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports/24599400#24599400

Answer (score 1):

Steps to analyze crash report from apple:

Copy the release .app file which was pushed to the appstore, the .dSYM file that was created at the time of release and the crash report receive from APPLE into a FOLDER.

OPEN terminal application and go to the folder created above (using cd command)

Run atos -arch armv7 -o APPNAME.app/APPNAME MEMORY_LOCATION_OF_CRASH. The memory location should be the one at which the app crashed as per the report.

Ex:  atos -arch armv7  -o 'APPNAME.app'/'APPNAME' 0x0003b508

This would show you the exact line, method name which resulted in crash.

Ex: [classname functionName:]; -510

Symbolicating IPA

if we use IPA for symbolicating - just rename the extention .ipa with .zip , extract it then we can get a Payload Folder which contain app. In this case we don't need .dSYM file.

Note

This can only work if the app binary does not have symbols stripped. By default release builds stripped the symbols. We can change it in project build settings "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" to NO.

Edit:

There are 3 assets that have to fit together when symbolicating a crash log:

The crash log file itself (i.e. example.crash), either exported from XCode's organizer or received from iTunes Connect.
The .app package (i.e. example.app) that itself contains the app binary belonging to the crash log. I you have an .ipa package (i.e. example.ipa) then you can extract the .app package by unzipping the .ipa package (i.e. unzip example.ipa). Afterwards the .app package resides in the extracted Payload/ folder.
The .dSYM package containing the debug symbols (i.e. example.app.dSYM)
Before starting symbolication you should check if all those artifacts match, which means that the crash log belongs to the binary you have and that the debug symbols are the ones produced during the build of that binary.

Each binary is referred by a UUID that can be seen in the crash log file:

...
Binary Images:
   0xe1000 -   0x1f0fff +example armv7   /var/mobile/Applications/9FB5D11F-42C0-42CA-A336-4B99FF97708F/example.app/example
0x2febf000 - 0x2fedffff  dyld armv7s  <4047d926f58e36b98da92ab7a93a8aaf> /usr/lib/dyld
...
In this extract the crash log belongs to an app binary image named example.app/example with UUID aa5e633efda8346cab92b01320043dc3.

You can check the UUID of the binary package you have with dwarfdump:

dwarfdump --uuid example.app/example
UUID: AA5E633E-FDA8-346C-AB92-B01320043DC3 (armv7) example.app/example
Afterwards you should check if the debug symbols you have also belong to that binary:

dwarfdump --uuid example.app.dSYM
UUID: AA5E633E-FDA8-346C-AB92-B01320043DC3 (armv7) example.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/example
In this example all assets fit together and you should be able to symbolicate your stacktrace.

Proceeding to the symbolicatecrash script:

In the latest XCode version you should be able to invoke the script via

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v example.crash 2> symbolicate.log
If it is not there you may run a find . -name symbolicatecrash in your XCode.app directory to find it.

As you can see there are no more parameters given. So the script has to find your application binary and debug symbols by running a spotlight search. It searches the debug symbols with a specific index called com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids. You can do this search yourself:

mdfind 'com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids = *'
resp.

mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == AA5E633E-FDA8-346C-AB92-B01320043DC3"
The first spotlight invocation gives you all indexed dSYM packages and the second one gives you the .dSYM packages with a specific UUID. If spotlight does not find your .dSYM package then symbolicatecrash will neither. If you do all this stuff e.g. in a subfolder of your ~/Desktop spotlight should be able to find everything.

If symbolicatecrash finds your .dSYM package there should be a line like the following in symbolicate.log:

@dsym_paths = ( /example.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/example )
For finding your .app package a spotlight search like the following is invoked by symbolicatecrash:

mdfind "kMDItemContentType == com.apple.application-bundle && (kMDItemAlternateNames == 'example.app' || kMDItemDisplayName == 'example' || kMDItemDisplayName == 'example.app')"
If symbolicatecrash finds your .app package there should be the following extract in symbolicate.log:

Number of symbols in /example.app/example: 2209 + 19675 = 21884
Found executable /example.app/example
-- MATCH
If all those resources are found by symbolicatecrash it should print out the symbolicated version of your crash log.

link: [source link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

And finally TEST TEST TEST

Comment: seems a little complicated ... anyway thanks for reply

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper-Italy it seems complicated because it is complicated. This is a detailed answer though.

Comment: One addition: calling `atos` should also get the `load address` passed along. The load address is the first address under the `Binary Images` section for the corresponding binary image.

Comment: This answer helps him symbolicate his crashlog which he appears to have updated his question with however it doesn't help solve the reason for the crash.

Comment: The question has been modified from the original to ask for further assistance. The answer I provided was relevant to the original question

Answer (score 0):

The real crash is thread 4. I'm getting similar crashes when invoking on the javascript context in a UIWebView. It's an intermittent crash and I have been unable to track it down.